# How do I offer a choice of shipping method to the user in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to WooCommerce. I feel like what I am looking to do is really simple, but I can't seem to find a solution. Basically, my store only consists of one product. I want to offer free shipping for that product as a default, but also provide the option for expedited shipping at a flat rate. What's the best and easiest way to do that?

Comment: in the settings of woocommerce, you can choose many shipping method and then the customer choose one at the checkout.

Comment: I created a zone for the United States and created 2 shipping methods: one for Free Shipping and one for Flat Rate, but nothing is showing on the cart page. Where else should I be looking as to why it's not displaying? Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: in the shipping options, have you set "Enable the shipping calculator on the basket page" ?

Comment: Yes, I have Enable the Shipping Calculator on the cart page checked!